# Multiple filter react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I have a react app that fetches some data from api. I need to filter it now. I've done a category filter but I need filter through price range now so these two filters could work together. I use two input to enter filter criteria.

The data from api is inside of state and looks like this

```
data = [
  { name: 'Audi',category: 'cars',  price: 132342 },
  { name: 'Macbook', category: 'laptops', price: 1322 },
  { name: 'Canon', category: 'cameras', price: 13342 },
  { name: 'Nikon', category: 'cameras', price: 12342 },
  { name: 'BMW', category: 'auto', price: 1655 }, etc];
```

The category filter I made:

```
state = {
        data: [],
        category: 'all'
    }
```

```
const visible = this.filter(data, category);

filter(items, filter){
        switch(filter){
            case 'all':
                return items;
            case 'auto':
                return items.filter((e) => e.category === 'cars');
            case 'cameras':
                return items.filter((e) => e.category === 'cameras');
            case 'laptops':
                return items.filter((e) => e.category === 'laptops');
            default:
                return items;
        }
    }
```

```
<select 
    id = 'category'
    value = {filter}
    onChange = { changeFilter }>
    { option }
</select>
changeFilter = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            category: event.target.value
        })
    }
```

How can add a price range filter to this?

Comment: do you want multi-select or multiple checkboxes?

Comment: multi-select I guess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple filters in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57358605/multiple-filters-in-react)

Comment: You just asked the same question yesterday for a different set of data?

Comment: I did, but I didn't get any answer

Comment: use logic here, set the response to state. Like if `a` is response, `setState({ filterData: a, data:a})` then render the `filterData` in DOM. on filter event, take the `filterData` from `state` filter it and set to `filterData`, again on the other filter, we have the first filtered data in `filterData` again filter it. on reset  reassign the `data` from state to `filterData`

Answer (score 0):

I would would construct the filters with higher order functions (functions that return functions).

```js
const chainFilters = filters => value => filters.every(f => f(value))

const itemFilters = (category, min, max) => chainFilters([
  v => !category || category === 'all' || v.category === category,
  v => min === undefined || v.price >= min,
  v => max === undefined || v.price <= max,
])

const items =  [
  { name: 'Audi',category: 'cars',  price: 132342 },
  { name: 'Macbook', category: 'laptops', price: 1322 },
  { name: 'Canon', category: 'cameras', price: 13342 },
  { name: 'Nikon', category: 'cameras', price: 12342 },
  { name: 'BMW', category: 'auto', price: 1655 }
]

console.log('cameras price < 13000:\n' ,items.filter(itemFilters('cameras', 0, 13000)))

console.log('cars:\n', items.filter(itemFilters('cars')))

console.log('all price < 2000:\n', items.filter(itemFilters('all', 0, 2000)))
```